# Zooming Charts (Image Format) displayed on SharePoint Home Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, chart

I've created a SharePoint Home Page where I would like to insert a chart or any image. Once I click on the Image / Chart, same should get zoomed on the same page i.e. a pop up of the zoomed Image should appear on the same page.

I'm not familiar with HTML coding so please do provide me step to step process to be followed.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work with the SharePoint "InHouse" functions. So you have to use HTML and JavaScript instead. But i am not sure if this works in the HTML-Page Editor so easily:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028557/how-to-zoom-in-an-image-and-center-it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find below HTML code which zooms the image on mouse rollover on the image.

.zoomin img { height: 200px; width: 200px; -webkit-transition: all 2s ease; -moz-transition: all 2s ease; -ms-transition: all 2s ease; transition: all 2s ease; } .zoomin img:hover { width: 300px; height: 300px; }

I want if someone could show me a code on how the image can be zoomed once clicked on it by editing the above code.

Many Thanks for your help in advance.